# PayPal "Security header is not valid" error. What to do with this?

Tags: security, paypal, payment-gateway

I am using PayPal's DoDirectPayment API for payment integration. I am getting an error message like below.

---

```
Security error:
Error no: 10002
Error message: Security header is not valid
```

---

Here is my code,

```
    $environment = 'sandbox';
    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $API_UserName = urlencode('xxxxxxxx');
    $API_Password = urlencode('xxxxxxxx');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('51.0');

    // setting the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Set the curl parameters.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

Please help me out from this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to check your API endpoint and version very carefully:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/

Comment: link has been removed from site

Answer (score 3):

1. goto https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts
2. login
3. create a Business account
4. click on the business account, click profile, click API Credentials and use the to access the api https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

Answer (score 0):

My problem occurred due to api credentials being incorrect.  Even after entering the correct sandbox api username, password and api key, I still got the same error. I recreated my test accounts, entered them into my app again, restarted the server, and it worked.

Here's a link from x.com talking about a similar issue: [paypal security header issue](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/xspaces/security-header-not-valid-paypal-pro-nvp)

Answer (score 0):

you should change your Endpoint api.sandbox.paypal.com, it worked on me
First you login to account sendbox and check in tab application

Answer (score 0):

user2230647 is right. You need to have sandbox information for all the following parameters in case you want to test in sandbox mode:

```
'api_endpoint'  => 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp', 
'api_username'  => 'example_api1.email.com', 
'api_password'  => 'your_password', 
'api_signature' => 'your_signature',
```